# Python: count specific occurrences in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, find-occurrences

Say I have a dictionary like this:

```
d={
'0101001':(1,0.0), 
'0101002':(2,0.0),
'0101003':(3,0.5),
'0103001':(1,0.0),
'0103002':(2,0.9),
'0103003':(3,0.4),
'0105001':(1,0.0),
'0105002':(2,1.0),
'0105003':(3,0.0)}
```

Considering that the first four digits of each key consitute the identifier of a "slot" of elements (e.g., '0101', '0103', '0105'), how can I count the number of occurrences of `0.0` for each slot?

The intended outcome is a dict like this:

```
result={
'0101': 2,
'0103': 1,
'0105': 2}
```

Apologies for not being able to provide my attempt as I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), add the first four digits of the key if the value is what you're looking for:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()

for key, value in d.items():
    if value[1] == 0.0:
        counts[key[:4]] += 1

print counts
```

Comment: Tried that. It says `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. It points at `for key, value in d:`.

Comment: We need `d.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from _collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
for k in d:
    if d[k][1] == 0.0:
        res[k[:4]] += 1

print(dict(res))
```

When you do the `+=1`, if the key does not exist, it creates it with value `0` and then does the operation.